Cannot perform Windows authentication with Oracle DB
I am trying to connect to my Oracle DB with Windows authentication, and it just doesn't seem to work - Whatever I do I keep getting "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied".
I installed Oracle DB version 21c, and upon that created a new windows user as the Oracle Home User. My global DB name is orcl.ad11.siemens.net, and the PDB is orclpdb.
I've created a new listener with the following configuration in listener.ora:
LISTENER_2 =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
            (ADDRESS =   (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = PNPKEY))))

SID_LIST_LISTENER_2 =
    (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
            (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCLPDB.AD11.SIEMENS.NET)
            (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\OraDB21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home)
            (SID_NAME = ORCLPDB)))

And added an alias in tnsnames.ora:
LISTENER_2 =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB.AD11.SIEMENS.NET)))

When I execute "lsnrctl status LISTENER_2", I get:
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_2
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                05-DEC-2024 15:18:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               admin
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\Oracle\OraDB21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\Oracle\OraDB21c\diag\tnslsnr\<my-hostname>\listener_2\alert\log.xml
Listener Trace File       C:\Oracle\OraDB21c\diag\tnslsnr\<my-hostname>\listener_2\trace\ora_23584_28284.trc
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\PNPKEYipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=<my-hostname>.ad11.siemens.net)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\ORACLE\ORADB21C\admin\orcl\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "75b0d2bd17c4485c998c967244b4515d.ad11.siemens.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLPDB.AD11.SIEMENS.NET" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLPDB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "bc74b627f47a416ab26784e660b5c7b2.ad11.siemens.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl.ad11.siemens.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.ad11.siemens.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

I noticed the status of ORCLPDB is UNKNOWN but I have no idea why - guess it might be something to consider as the source of the problem.
Additionally, I added the following line to sqlnet.ora:
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)

And I also granted my current windows user with the required privileges, and it's verified by the fact that:
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = ORCLPDB;
SELECT USERNAME, AUTHENTICATION_TYPE FROM DBA_USERS WHERE AUTHENTICATION_TYPE = 'EXTERNAL';

Returns my current windows user.
I use the following command to connect:
sqlplus /@LISTENER_2

And tried many other ways as well, but keep getting that ORA-01017.
Does anyone have a clue what is the problem here and how can I fix it?
